# Best way to know the algorithm used for a password encryption

Tags: passwords, mysql, decryption

I have the following password captured using sqlmap-

```
 $2a$08$9eaKUtKdFV8fuOAx0sfr4emrG1aHzGeNsn/rVdW243nw6Ktt.Uc0O
```

Now, I don't know how to decrypt this password because I don't know which algorithm was used for its encryption.

I have tried online free decryption tools, but none of them find the way to discover which algorithm was used.

Comment: *"I have tried online free decryption tools, but none of them find the way to discover which algorithm was used."*  most passwords generated in most programming languages nowadays uses a **internal salt so (online) rainbow tables becomes useless**.. Notice [this](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/00f10fd98661089c86d1a3c2fb916d72a623dede) (PHP) code and see the hash is different foreach run even for the same password.. Also blowfish is slow to run on GPU's so bruteforcing on GPUs is also not a option

Comment: Ok i am going to check the link for guidance and thanks for your precious time.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## How are passwords stored?

Passwords are not (or at least should not be) stored using encryption. They should be stored using a hashing algorithm. So if you are trying to decrypt it to recover the original password, then that isn't going to work.

Here are some links to read about how password storage works:

- https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm#normalhashing
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function#Password_verification
- and a much, much longer one here: https://security.blogoverflow.com/2013/09/about-secure-password-hashing/

## How to figure out which hash algorithm was used?

Let's break down your sample password:

*(This section is completely quoted from A. Hersean answer below. Please scroll down and give them an upvote)*

According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt) and [the passlib documentation](https://passlib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/lib/passlib.hash.bcrypt.html) we can deduce :

- "$" is a separator
- "2a" means that the algorithm used is bcrypt with the blowfish hashing function;
- "08" is the cost parameter, i.e. 2^8 rounds;
- "9eaKUtKdFV8fuOAx0sfr4e" is the 128 bit salt encoded in Radix64;
- "mrG1aHzGeNsn/rVdW243nw6Ktt.Uc0O" is the hash encoded in Radix64.

Even knowing that it's a hash and not encryption, it's still hard to reverse-engineer which hash algorithm was used (this is by design).

## Tools to identify hash type

If you google for "hash identifier tools", you'll find plenty of free websites. Personally, I like the linux command-line tool `hash-identifier` (in Kali, or `hashid` in Ubuntu):

```
~ hashid 
$2a$08$9eaKUtKdFV8fuOAx0sfr4emrG1aHzGeNsn/rVdW243nw6Ktt.Uc0O
Analyzing '$2a$08$9eaKUtKdFV8fuOAx0sfr4emrG1aHzGeNsn/rVdW243nw6Ktt.Uc0O'
[+] Blowfish(OpenBSD) 
[+] Woltlab Burning Board 4.x 
[+] bcrypt
```

I hope this has been helpful!

Comment: Very nice, your theory is very clear, now i got it what is this... In fact i was totally wrong about the password hashing (I thought it is encrypted string) but yes it is hash not encryption- thanks for very good clarifications and also for important links for reading...

Comment: `$id` is a [standard format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crypt_%28C%29) and `$2a` is [a version of bcrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt#Versioning_history)

Comment: I added an answer in complement to yours (a comment would have been too long). Feel free to include it in your answer if you wish so, I would then delete mine.

Comment: @A.Hersean Thanks! I've referenced your answer so that hopefully you still get some upvotes.

Comment: I did not answer to get upvotes, but thank you for your kind consideration. I'll leave my answer then.

Comment: You forgot to mention that most passwords generated in most programming languages nowadays uses a **internal salt so (online) rainbow tables becomes useless**.. Notice [this](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/00f10fd98661089c86d1a3c2fb916d72a623dede) (PHP) code and see the hash is different foreach run even for the same password.. Also blowfish is slow to run on GPU's so bruteforcing on GPUs is also not a option

Answer (score 4):

To complement the answer of Mike Ounsworth, according to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt) and [the passlib documentation](https://passlib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/lib/passlib.hash.bcrypt.html) we can deduce :

- "$" is a separator
- "2a" means that the algorithm used is bcrypt with the blowfish hashing function;
- "08" is the cost parameter, i.e. 2^8 rounds;
- "9eaKUtKdFV8fuOAx0sfr4e" is the 128 bit salt encoded in Radix64;
- "mrG1aHzGeNsn/rVdW243nw6Ktt.Uc0O" is the hash encoded in Radix64.

Comment: very nice details- love your answer too...